# jQuery variables inside RenderPartial loop

Tags: jquery

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this, but I'm not finding it :)

I have a page, it has a loop, in this loop it calls a RenderPartial

```
foreach(var thing in Things)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("Graph", thing)
}
```

In this RenderPartial, I am creating a graph

```
var myGraph = new Graph(various things here)
myGraph.Draw();
```

The problem is, now the page that I called the RenderPartial from has a bunch of graph objects, all named myGraph and I can't address any of them specifically.  How can I construct a compound variable name so that each graph has a different name?  Only one graph is created for each call of the RenderPartial so an array doesn't work.

Comment: What's `RenderPartial`? What's `Html`? What's a `Graph`? What's that library you are using?

Comment: @Brian - I think `RenderPartial` is server-side ASP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"jQuery variables"*

These aren't jQuery variables, they're JavaScript variables. jQuery is "just" a library of JavaScript functions, and the code that you've shown doesn't include any use of jQuery.

> *"now the page that I called the RenderPartial from has a bunch of graph objects, all named `myGraph` and I can't address any of them specifically."*

Actually it has only one `myGraph` variable that you keep overwriting, so you can only ever address the last one. (And the earlier `Graph` objects would be garbage-collected because there'd be no references to them.)

> *"Only one graph is created for each call of the RenderPartial so an array doesn't work."*

I don't understand why you think an array won't work. Declare it before your loop:

```
var myGraphs = [],
    currentGraph;
```

...and then in the RenderPartial inside the loop add to the array:

```
myGraphs.push(currentGraph = new Graph(...));
currentGraph.Draw();
// do any other operations on currentGraph within the loop
```

Or without using a `currentGraph` variable you can do this:

```
myGraphs.push(new Graph(...));
myGraphs[myGraphs.length - 1].Draw();
```

Either way, in other code later on your page you can then perform operations on any or all of the `Graph` objects by accessing them as array elements. E.g., to redraw them all:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myGraphs.length; i++)
   myGraphs[i].Draw();
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the push syntax to make a dynamic array. That solves the issue nicely!

Comment: You're welcome. Of course you can say `myGraphs[myGraphs.length] = new Graph();` to add an item to the end, but `.push()` is nicer.